# How do I add a navigation bar on top of background?

Tags: html, css

So Im currently creating a webpage, and I want to put a navigation bar at the top, but for some reason its not showing even though I set the colour of it to black in my CSS. I need the header "JG.OFFICIAL" to be inside the nav since its the logo. But it does not seem to be working well, some advice is appreciated.

My site: https://jgofficial1.000webhostapp.com/index.html

Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
}
  body {
  background-image: url("../images/hello.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
}
nav {
  color: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
    <div class="header-logo">
        <h1>JG.OFFICIAL</h1>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h2>There's Still a bit of work to be done, come back soon</h2>
```

Comment: Currently you're setting the color black, not the background-color

Comment: On your actual website both the header and ul are outside of the `nav` element. And `color` sets text colour, for background you want `background-color`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare `background: black;` in `nav` if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow!! thank you so much, I felt like an idiot not picking that up :)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property for setting background color is `background` or `background-color` and not `color`.

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../images/hello.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="header-logo">
    <h1>JG.OFFICIAL</h1>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>

<h2>There's Still a bit of work to be done, come back soon</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../images/hello.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #e76160;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="header-logo">
    <h1>JG.OFFICIAL</h1>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>

<h2>There's Still a bit of work to be done, come back soon</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]There are other problems besides the background color. I've put in a few inline styles using Chrome that may be helpful to see some possible changes. You also have an element at the bottom with a `z-index` that's amazingly high. You may want to reconsider that number as I don't know of a good reason to have a `z-index` that's 2 billion something.

```
<html>
  <head>        
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JG.OFFICAL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">        
    <!--fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Montserrat:600" rel="stylesheet">    
  </head>


  <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true">

    <nav>        
      <div class="header-logo" style="
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 50px;">
        <h1>JG.OFFICIAL</h1>
      </div>

      <ul style="
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 650px;">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2>There's Still a bit of work to be done, come back soon</h2>
    <!-- the rest of your body -->
  </body>
```